# How to block PROPFIND and allow only GET method?

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm using Apache and I need to restrict the allowed methods for a specific location.
Specifically, I want to prevent users from using the `PROPFIND` method, and ideally restrict them to only making HTTP `GET` requests.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to totally deny all `PROPFIND` requests, consider disabling DAV. If you want DAV to be usable and just want to disable everything-but-GET for unauthenticated users, use something like:

```
<Location />
    <LimitExcept GET>
        Require valid-user
        # Or whatever makes sense in your case
    </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```